# How to Move ldf&mdf from sql server into Extenal Memory

Tags: sql-server, database, mdf

I have a database in my sql . i want to have a copy/move it to another computer.
when i go to directory of ldf&mdf file,and want to copy them, error "Access Denied" occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier way to migrate is through the backup/restore commands.

But in you case if the SQL Server service is running? In this case you  need to stop first.

When the service was stop I'm pretty sure that all permission at the files will be dropped so you need to have some administrator power to given yourself the permission again.